# Fetching login times for cognito user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm fairly new to AWS and was wondering if there is a place in AWS that stores cognito users login times. I want to be able to present a table consisting of the previous succesful login attempts of a specific user. I know I could do that from the client side by storing the time and date in a db everytime they user logs in, but I was just wondering if there was an API I could call that already stores that data for me.

Comment: Hi. Did you find something like that?